# Certificates for autoscaling internal networks?

Tags: authentication, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, kerberos

A public website with an SSL certificate makes use of a certificate and CA in order to establish trust between the server and client.

How is the same thing typically implemented on private networks, with large numbers of short-lived hosts, such as in an autoscaling cluster? Copying the public key of every host to every other host would not scale well if hosts are frequently being created & destroyed.

Do people usually set up a private CA? Or use a symmetric key approach like Kerberos? Or some other approach? Are there any specific approaches recommended or provided by cloud providers, like AWS, GCP or Azure?

**Note:** I'm not asking for the technical details of *how* to set this up. I'm asking what the general approach is.

Comment: How this is done in private network is by running your own CA. It's very common practice and is a little bit like asking how to bake your own cookies. But after that, you ask about how it's done with autoscaling clusters, which I don't know! The CA system would perfectly work, but I can imagine there are some considerations that are not relevant in a regular setup. That's a good question. Perhaps it makes sense to focus the question on that? Could you clarify what properties you're looking for, e.g. mutual trust between the client and server, or just one way?

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16740/internal-ssl-certificates?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal SSL Certificates?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16740/internal-ssl-certificates)

Comment: @Luc - Is that the way cloud providers recommend you do it? And do they generally provide tools to do this? (By the way, you could turn your comment in to an answer.)

Comment: @schroeder and yoozer8 - Those questions are about setting up SSL certificates. I'm not asking *how* to set up an SSL certificate. I'm asking whether setting up an SSL certificate is the recommended way to solve this problem, or whether another approach like Kerberos or manually distributing public keys is the more common way to solve this.

Comment: @aco Sorry, you misunderstood me: I'm not really answering your question. I don't know if an internal CA is the way to do it for anything other than stable networks. If lots of nodes in a cluster are spun up and down, I doubt the CA system scales easily. But I don't really know because I never dealt with that. I think you should clarify the question (just modify the title and text, don't add an edit section) to make it more focused on "is this good practice with autoscaling?" instead of just "can this be done?" (it can definitely be done with openssl or so).

Comment: @Luc - Good idea, will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An internal CA is the usual approach. You can generate certificates for each server with a short renewal time and have the internal CA root installed on your internal client machines (e.g. via group policy). You then set up some certificate management infrastructure to help you generate and deploy certificates.

As an example, [Kubernetes maintains a CA per cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/), which allows each component and workload to securely communicate during administration tasks. They utilise [CFSSL](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cfssl/) for doing the heavy lifting, which is the same toolset that allows Cloudflare to automatically deploy and manage certificates at scale.

Comment: This is a good explanation - thanks! Also discovered that AWS has its own private CA as a service: https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/private-certificate-authority/

Answer (score 0):

You may use Cloudflare's PKI and TLS Toolkit - it is a suite of utilities (cfssl is one of them) that can be easily embedded into data center automation (shell scripts, Ansible roles/playbooks and such).
You can quickly set up a PKI with multiple Certificate Authorities with also an online Registration Authority endpoint that you can use for automatic enrollment. Client side, you can use certmgr to either request new certificates or monitor enrolled renewals for the expiring ones. As for the Validation Authority part, it supports both CRL and OCSP. Certificates can embed Authority Information Access, and with a little bit of tweaking you can even issue certificates that embed the Certification Practice Statement and custom policies too.

Comment: Welcome to the community. The OP hasn't specified the deployment scenario (on-prem or cloud) but then at least give a brief pros and cons for and against using cloud services for this matter. It's not even known whether OP wants the webapp/website/whatever open to the internet which makes a big difference.